# Removing Wordpress Footer -without access to PHP code?

Tags: php, css, templates

I want to remove the "powered by wordpress" and theme name in the footer, but all the tutorials refer to clicking on the "Appearance" tab, clicking on an edit button, and then going to the php templates on the right sidebar.  It seems like Wordpress has changed since these tutorials and is no longer allowing access to php templates.  No matter what I do to the CSS code, the footer is not budging. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: WordPress absolutely allows access to theme templates in `Editor`. Is that publicly available theme? This is very hard to answer "in theory", too many possibilities.

Comment: Hi @DSW - If you can give more info it would help. Do you have the name of the theme? Do you have a URL for the site where you can point us? Why can you not access to your site code via FTP? Why can you not find the file in `/wp-content/themes/%your_theme%/footer.php` where `%your_theme%` in the directory where your theme is located?

Comment: It sounds like to me that your files aren't writeable. Does it say this "You need to make this file writable before you can save your changes." at the bottom of your theme file options? You need to change the permissions of the theme folder via ftp or ssh to access the files.

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking it in the PHP code shouldn't be too hard. You don't need to really know any PHP at all. Just need to `CTRL+F` to find that phrase you want to remove.

But if you absolutely want to do it with just CSS, it is possible to hide it with `{display:none}`. The code will still load, but just be hidden from visibility to a user. You will need to find the class, id, or html element that contains that text though.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this simple CSS tweak. No need to touch PHP code.

```
#credit{
    display: none;
}
```

Depending your theme and installation, the word `credit` may need to change. This word is the ID associated with the underlying visual element you want removed/hidden. To correctly find the ID used in your specific situation, right click on the element you want to hide and inspect that element and then look for something like this.

```
id="credit"
```

This ID needs to match the CSS to correctly suppress that element associated with this ID.

Answer (score 0):

Access the footer.php file using FTP and download it to your local computer.

Open the file using a code editor like Notepad++

Find the code which looks like this:

```
do_action( 'twentyten_credits' ); ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentyten' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s.', 'twentyten' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
```

Remove the links

Example:

REMOVE http://wordpress.org/ AND ANY OTHER LINKS YOU DON'T WANT DISPLAYED

```
do_action( 'twentyten_credits' ); ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( '', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentyten' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s.', 'twentyten' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
```

Or you could simply remove all the code excluding any hooks like this:

```
do_action( 'twentyten_credits' ); ?>
```

Then upload the file back to your themes root directory over riding the footer.php file.

You should add the modified footer.php file (without the footer links) to a [child theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19174878/2589071) otherwise it will be lost when you update the parent theme.